# Expression.Error: The column 'BackLogCount' of the table wasn't found. - PowerBI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "BackLogCount", each if [COMMENTS] = [PrevComments] then [#"COUNT(MM.COMMENTS)"] + Source[#"BackLogCount"]{0} else [#"COUNT(MM.COMMENTS)"], type number)

I am creating a column named BacklogCount(under Edit Queries) and I am refering to the same column header in my DAX query?
This will not work in PowerBi?
Requesting your feedback.

Comment: why do you call it "DAX query"? This is not DAX.